# Converting number to India Locale Format

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I was trying to convert a number say `123456.789` to India Locale Format wiz `1,23,456.789` as India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators.

I was successfully able to do this with some 10-20 lines of code and then I came to this article of MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Using_locales

You see the line 11, they have declared a mechanism there to convert it

```
// India uses thousands/lakh/crore separators
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
// → 1,23,456.789
```

But it is not working (tested in Chrome v49.0.2623 and Safari)

```
Output in safari:
123456.789

Output in chrome:
123,456.789
```

But it worked in firefox

```
Output in Firefox:
1,23,456.789
```

**But when I read the browser compatibility table it was stated that it is supported in chrome v24+**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```js
var number = 123456.789
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
```

Comment: Supporting the method isn't the same thing as supporting every particular locale and its associated formatting rules. Entirely possible that it's a "bug" in Chrome and Safari where they don't have any India specific formatting rules for numbers, so it falls back to the default.

Comment: I think it may just be the `'en-IN'` input. An input of `'hi'`(Hindi) in Chrome returns `1,23,456.789` as expected.

Answer (score 9):

This simply means that the `en-IN` locale code isn't supported by Chrome (or Safari). You may have better luck using a different locale which uses the same format. An example of this is the Hindi locale code (`hi`), which seems to return this format in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 11:

```
console.log((123456.789).toLocaleString('hi'));
-> 1,23,456.789
```

For what it's worth, MDN's support table only lists *Basic Support*. It determines which browsers implement the functionality, but it doesn't go as far as testing every possible use case.